# Why my pygame code is crashing with "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object"?

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, rpg

I want to put a system of collide on my pygame's rpg and my code is crashing with "RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded while calling a Python object". I tried many things but the error always appears.

My code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
from player import *

class Camera:
    def __init__(self, widht, height):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, widht, height)
        self.widht = widht
        self.height = height
        self.center = list(self.rect.center)
        self.x = self.center[0]
        self.y = self.center[1]

    def apply(self, entity):
        return entity.move(self.rect.topleft)
    def update(self, target):
        y = -target.rect.y + int(769 / 2)
        x = -target.rect.x + int(1024 / 2)
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, self.widht, self.height)


class Level(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self):
        self.structure = 0
        self.all_blocks = pygame.sprite.Group()


    def generer(self):
        with open("niveau.txt", "r") as fichier:
            structure_niveau = []
            for ligne in fichier:
                ligne_niveau = []
                for sprite in ligne:
                    if sprite != '\n':
                        ligne_niveau.append(sprite)
                structure_niveau.append(ligne_niveau)
            self.structure = structure_niveau

    def afficher(self, fenetre, x, y, camX, camY, playerX, playerY):
        tailleSprite = 64
        self.all_blocks.empty()
        #Camera.__init__(self, x, y)
        cam = Camera(1024, 768)

        grass = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/grass.png").convert_alpha()

        tree = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/tree_grass.png").convert_alpha()

        no_texture = pygame.image.load("assets/bloc/no_texture.png").convert_alpha()

        num_ligne = 0
        for ligne in self.structure:
            num_case = 0
            for sprite in ligne:
                x = num_case * tailleSprite + camX
                y = num_ligne * tailleSprite + camY
                sprite_rect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 64, 64)
                screenRect = pygame.Rect(x, y, 1088, 836)
                aroundPlayer = pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, playerX + 128, playerY + 128)
                if sprite == 'G':
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(grass, (x, y))
                        if aroundPlayer.contains(sprite_rect):
                            self.all_blocks.add(sprite)

                elif sprite == 'T':
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(tree, (x, y))
                        #self.all_blocks.add(sprite)
                    #print(self.x, self.y)

                else:
                    if screenRect.contains(sprite_rect):
                        fenetre.blit(no_texture, (x, y))
                    #print(x, y)

                num_case += 1
            num_ligne += 1
```

and main.py:

```
import pygame
from game import Game
from level import *
pygame.init()

lvl = Level()
WIDHT = 768
HEIGHT = 1024
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024, 768))
screen_rect = pygame.Rect(0, 0, HEIGHT, WIDHT)
pygame.display.set_caption("RPG") 
game = Game()
cam = Camera(1024, 768)
running = True
lvl.generer()
print(game.player.rect)
print(screen_rect)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, 0, 0, game.player.rect.x, game.player.rect.y)
camPos = 0

while running:
    lvl.afficher(screen, 0, 0, camPos, 0, game.player.rect.x, game.player.rect.y)
    cam.apply(game.player.rect)
    cam.update(game.player)
    #print(cam.rect.topleft)
    if game.pressed.get(pygame.K_RIGHT):
        game.player.move_right()
        #print(game.player.rect.x)
        if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
            game.player.rect.x -= HEIGHT -60 
            camPos += -HEIGHT

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_LEFT):
        game.player.move_left()
        #print(game.player.rect.x)
        if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
            game.player.rect.x += HEIGHT - 60
            camPos += HEIGHT

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_DOWN):
        game.player.move_down()
        #print(game.player.rect.y)
        if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
            game.player.rect.y -= WIDHT - 80

    elif game.pressed.get(pygame.K_UP):
        game.player.move_up()
        #print(game.player.rect.y)
        if not screen_rect.contains(game.player.rect):
            game.player.rect.y += WIDHT - 80

    #print(cam.rect.x, cam.rect.y)
    #print(cam.rect)

    screen.blit(game.player.image, game.player.rect)

    pygame.display.flip()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
             game.pressed[event.key] = True

        elif event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            game.pressed[event.key] = False
```

Comment: Maybe I'm blind but I don't see any recursion in this example. Is there any code that you didn't post (e.g. `player`?)  Also please include the full error traceback.

Comment: Your question should include a [mre] and all available details about the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try one of the following option which will help you to get rid of the error

1. try to change the algorithm from recursive to iterative
2. you can change the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit(n)` - in python recursion is limited to 999 calls.

Comment: Oh thank you @zealous ! But how can y convert  the algorithm from recursive to iterative? I look on internet but I don'y understand how can y apply the conversion's method to my code ?

Comment: you may have to implement loop instead of calling function again and again. Just search online you will get few examples.If you like my answer then please click on the tick or give a vote by click on upward arrow. Thanks